# How to manage redundancy in Chef-repo and berkshelf cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, redundancy, cookbook, berkshelf

I am using Chef for automation. I have a chef-repo cookbook that has custom cookbooks as well as cookbooks from the opscode site.

As few cookbooks have dependency on other cookbooks I have installed those dependencies using berks utility.

Now my question is how can I manage the both the cookbooks and its redundancies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed answer,

You can mention your wrapper cookbooks and its dependencies in same berksfile. Cookbook source in "Beksfile", can be from "Chef Supermarket", GIT source, and system local path.

Consider cookbook "mysql_wrapper" is the cookbook developed by you and it uses "mysql" community cookbook. Also consider the wrapper is located in system local path.

Here is sample berksfile content for above scenario.

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook 'mysql'
cookbook 'mysql_wrapper', path: '/system/local/path/to/wrapper-cookbooks/mysql_wrapper'
```

***How it works?***

When you run "berks install" or "berks upload", Berkshelf resolves the cookbooks mentioned in berksfile.

Dependent community cookbook will be downloaded from "Supermarket", because we referenced it in first line. While the wrapper cookbook will be referenced by local path.

***Setting up a project for managing cookbooks, roles and data_bags***

- Create a project repository with your cookbooks and other stuff.
- Project repo is nothing but, a directory contains other directories for 1. Roles, 2. Databags, 3. Cookbooks and 4. Environments. According to your requirement create repository.
- Place your cookbooks inside cookbooks directory.
- Create a directory as "roles". Add roles as ".json" files.
- In case of data_bag/data_bag_item, create a directory as data_bags. Create a directory for each data_bag and add items as ".json" files.
- Create the bersfile inside the repo

***Manage Chef server***

In case, if you want to upload the content, follow the steps below,

- Create a directory ".chef" inside the project repo
- Copy your Chef server knife/pem files into .chef
- Run the command "berks upload" from inside the project repo. Your cookbooks will be uploaded to Chef server.
- Run knife upload data_bags and knife upload roles, to upload your databags and roles from the repo.